# Puppeteer: How to catch a popup and reliably wait for its load event?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

What is a reliable way to capture a popup with Puppeteer and wait for its initial load?

In my testing, the following code works most of the time, except when the page loads before `tgt.page()` resolves. If that happens, then the load event has already triggered when the listener is added, so the last promise waiting for the load event just times out.

I can't figure out how to get a reference to the page to add a listener before it begins loading.

```js
export async function waitForPopupMatching(
  browser: Puppeteer.Browser,
  regex: RegExp,
  openAction: () => Promise<void>,
  timeout: number = 30000,
): Promise<Puppeteer.Page> {
  let timer: NodeJS.Timer;
  const promise = new Bluebird<Puppeteer.Target>(resolve => {
    const listener = async (target: Puppeteer.Target) => {
      if (target.type() === 'page' && regex.test(target.url())) {
        browser.removeListener('targetcreated', listener);
        resolve(target);
      }
    };
    browser.addListener('targetcreated', listener);
  }).timeout(timeout);

  await openAction(); // Typically a mouse click

  const tgt = await promise;
  const page = await tgt.page();

  await new Bluebird(resolve => {
    page.once('load', () => resolve());
  }).timeout(timeout);

  return page;
}
```